# python: check if a certain number of characters in a key match those of another key in the same dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing

I have the following dictionary:

```
dic_raw={'M.ESE18.COFMSDM01V.MW.IT':{'initiativeType': 'Activation', 'initiativeName': 'Campaign1'},'M.ESE18.COFMSDM01V.MN.ML':{'initiativeType': 'Revokation', 'initiativeName': 'Campaign 2'},'M.ESE18.COFMSDM01V.CI.CR':{'initiativeType': 'Stratification', 'initiativeName': 'Campaign 3'},'M.ESE18.COFMSDM01A.OP.TA':{'initiativeType': 'Activation', 'initiativeName': 'Campaign 5'}, 'N.ESE18.FFFMSDM01A.NS.TA':{'initiativeType': 'Activation', 'initiativeName': 'Campaign 6'}, 'N.ESE18.FFFMSDM01A.OP.TA':{'initiativeType': 'Activation', 'initiativeName': 'Campaign 4'}}
```

What i would need is to create another dictionary (**dic_new**), with the same info as **dic_raw** + another level of depth for the keys. That new level of key in **dic_new** comes from the first 18 matching characters of any of the keys in the initial **dic_raw**, and it's value should be a nested dictionary of the "old" 18chars-matching keys + all their "old" values.

Like this:

```
dic_new={'M.ESE18.COFMSDM01V': {'M.ESE18.COFMSDM01V.MW.IT': {'initiativeType': 'Activation', 'initiativeName': 'Campaign 1'}, 'M.ESE18.COFMSDM01V.MN.ML': {'initiativeType': 'Revokation', 'initiativeName': 'Campaign 2'}, 'M.ESE18.COFMSDM01V.CI.CR': {'initiativeType': 'Stratification', 'initiativeName': 'Campaign 3'}}, 'N.ESE18.FFFMSDM01A':{'N.ESE18.FFFMSDM01A.NS.TA': {'initiativeType': 'Activation', 'initiativeName': 'Campaign 6'}, 'N.ESE18.FFFMSDM01A.OP.TA': {'initiativeType': 'Activation', 'initiativeName': 'Campaign 4'}}, 'M.ESE18.COFMSDM01A':{'M.ESE18.COFMSDM01A.OP.TA':  {'initiativeType': 'Activation', 'initiativeName': 'Campaign 5'}}}
```

E.g:

- the first key '**M.ESE18.COFMSDM01V**.MW.IT' would be compared with all the other keys in the initial dictionary
- because its first 18 characters are identical in the case of 2 other keys in the dictionary ('**M.ESE18.COFMSDM01V**.MN.ML','**M.ESE18.COFMSDM01V**.CI.CR'), then
- **M.ESE18.COFMSDM01V** (the common part of the 3 keys) will become a new "top-level" key in the new dict, with the matching 2 keys now turned into it's value as nested dictionaries

Therefore

```
 M.ESE18.COFMSDM01V.MW.IT:{'initiativeType': 'Activation','initiativeName': 'Campaign 1'}
 M.ESE18.COFMSDM01V.MN.ML:{'initiativeType': 'Revokation','initiativeName': 'Campaign 2'}
```

should become

```
M.ESE18.COFMSDM01V:{'M.ESE18.COFMSDM01V.MW.IT': {'initiativeType': 'Activation', 'initiativeName': 'Campaign 1'},'M.ESE18.COFMSDM01V.MN.ML': {'initiativeType': 'Revokation', 'initiativeName': 'Campaign 2'}}
```

Mentions:

- There will be multiple cases when several of the initial keys will
  have common characters and therefore would need to be included in a
  new top-level key, but i won't know which or how many
- Some keys in the dictionary will be completely unique (in terms of their first 18 chars), but i still need to create the same structure even for those in the new dictionary

I'm very new at programming, so i've tried going about the problem in multiple ways but i'm really not able to find a solution. I believe i'm unable to break the problem correctly down into the separate pieces (finding the matching keys in a character-by-character indexable way --couldn't figure out how do it in the dict so i needed to move the keys to a list but then i got stuck on how to do the comparison properly, then moving the part i need to a new dict while also copying as nested dicts it's old matching values, etc.)

Any help would be kindly appreciated!

Comment: Seems like you have adequately defined the problem/requirements - the next step would be to write down on paper the process (steps) you need to take to accomplish the task, then try and turn those steps into pseudocode, then finally Python code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way to make this easily :

```
dic_new = {}
for key, value in dic_raw.iteritems():
    dic_new.setdefault(key[:18], {}).setdefault(key, value)
```

Comment: Appreciate it Virginie! would you be so kind and write just a few words to help me understand how you thought the problem through?

Comment: No problem,
you want to group keys with the 18 first characters of keys so you need to add these informations in a new dict  (dic_new)
the function setdefault allow to define new keys in a dictionary in one line and simplify the script. For exemple, if the key doesn't exists, it is created with a dictionary {} by default and take the keys if key exists,
have you an another question ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dic_new={}
for k in dic_raw:
    nk = k[:18]
    if not nk in dic_new:
        dic_new[nk]={}
    dic_new[nk][k] = dic_raw[k]
```

Comment: Works equally well, appreciate it! I'd be very grateful if you could help me understand how you thought about it?

Comment: For each item in old list, if it doesn't exist in new list, create it, then append the extra data to the newly created item in new list.  Its a somewhat common exercise in programming, so I think its one of those things that you just have to see somebody else do it once and then its another tool on your belt.